# Neo4j floating point sum different results

Tags: neo4j, floating-point, sum, precision

I am using neo4j to calculate some statistics on a data set. For that I am often using sum on a floating point value. I am getting different results depending on the circumstances. For example, a query that does this:

```
...
WITH foo
ORDER BY foo.fooId
RETURN SUM(foo.Weight)
```

Returns different result than the query that simply does the sum:

```
...
RETURN SUM(foo.Weight)
```

The differences are miniscule (`293.07724195098984` vs `293.07724195099007`). But it is enough to make simple equality checks fail. Another example would be a different instance of the database, loaded with the same data using the same loading process can produce the same issue (the dbs might not be 1:1, the load order of some relations might be different). I took the raw values that neo4j sums (by simply removing the `SUM()`) and verified that they are the same in all cases (different dbs and ordered/not ordered).

What are my options here? I don't mind losing some precision (I already tried to cut down the precision from 15 to 12 decimal places but that did not seem to work), but I need the results to match up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of rounding errors, floats are not associative. (a+b)+c!=a+(b+c).
The result of every operation is rounded to fit the floats coding constraints and (a+b)+c is implemented as round(round(a+b) +c) while  a+(b+c) as round(a+round(b+c)).

As an obvious illustration, consider the operation (2^-100 + 1 -1). If interpreted as a (2^-100 + 1)-1, it will return 0, as 1+2^-100 would require a precision too large for floats or double coding in IEEE754 and can only be coded as 1.0. While (2^-100 +(1-1)) correctly returns 2^-100 that can be coded by either floats or doubles.
This is a trivial example, but these rounding errors may exist  after every operation and explain why floating point operations are not associative.

Databases generally do not return data in a garanteed order and depending on the actual order, operations will be done differently and that explains the behaviour that you   have.

In general, for this reason, it not a good idea to do equality comparison on floats. Generally, it is advised to replace a==b by abs(a-b) is "sufficiently" small.
"sufficiently" may depend on your algorithm. float are equivalent to ~6-7 decimals and doubles to 15-16 decimals (and I think that it is what is used on your DB). Depending on the number of computations, you may have the last 1--3 decimals affected.
The best is probably to use
abs(a-b)<relative-error*max(abs(a),abs(b))
where relative-error must be adjusted to your problem. Probably something around 10^-13 can be correct, but you must experiment, as rounding errors depends on the number of computations, on the dispersion of the values and on what you may consider as "equal" for you problem.

Look at [this site](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) for a discussion on comparison methods. And read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg that discusses, among others, these problems.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. In the end what I decided to do is put a round to truncate the float to 9 decimal places, which seems to have fixed our issues. I tried 12 but the issue still occurred in some queries. 9 is sufficient for our use case fortunately.